# Rules for factoring an inequality with a dot product ( a step for proving the Triangle Inequality Theorem)

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, factoring

Trying to understand the proof for the theorem

$$
\text{For any} \overrightarrow{u}, \overrightarrow{v} \in \mathbb{R}^n, \\
|\overrightarrow{u}+\overrightarrow{v}| \leq |\overrightarrow{u}| + |\overrightarrow{v}| \\
\text{with equality if and only if one of the vectors is a nonnegative scalar multiple of
the other one.}
$$

I came across one step in the proof that I don't understand. Namely the author of the book for linear algebra that I'm reading right now factors the inequality

$$
0 \leq |\overrightarrow{u}|^2|\overrightarrow{v}|^2 - 2(|\overrightarrow{v}|\overrightarrow{u}) \bullet (|\overrightarrow{u}|\overrightarrow{v}) + |\overrightarrow{u}|^2|\overrightarrow{v}|^2
$$

like so

$$
0 \leq (|\overrightarrow{u}|\overrightarrow{v} - |\overrightarrow{v}|\overrightarrow{u}) \bullet (|\overrightarrow{u}|\overrightarrow{v} - |\overrightarrow{v}|\overrightarrow{u})
$$

I do not understand this factorization step and would be glad if someone could help me. Thank you!

Book / location of the proof in the book:  Linear Algebra by Jim Hefferon (fourth edition) / page 44

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Maths SX!

You can use this notation for the dot product:
$\enspace\vec u\cdot \vec u=(\vec u)^2\enspace(=|\vec u|^2)$ ,  and it happens  that, by the basic properties of the dot product, the binomial formula is also valid for the dot product, i.e.:
$$(a\vec u+b\vec v)^2=a^2 (\vec u)^2+2ab\, \vec u\cdot\vec v+b^2(\vec v)^2$$

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer and the welcome @Bernard!

I could see that the factoring has something to do with the 2nd binomial formula... the part were I went wrong was that I did not apply the rule that a vector squared equals the magnitude of the vector squared and you can substitute each of the two expressions with the other so I was confused why for example 
$$ (|\vec u|\vec v)^2 = |\vec u|^2|\vec v|^2 $$.